# MongoDB aggregate return averages only where date key is greater than a specific date in PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection that looks something like this;

```
{_id: 1204187,
'name' : 'name',
'date' : 2020-06-21T00:00:00.000+00:00,
'metric_a' : 88.14502,
'metric_b' : 31.26421,
'metric_c' : 1544.32414,
'info' : {'foreign_key' : 156789,
          'country' : 'US',
          'tags' : ['a', 'b', 'c']}}
```

I would like to return aggregated docs, but only aggregate documents where the date is greater than 7-1-2020.
Here is my first attempt;

```
date_obj = dt.datetime(today.year, today.month, 1)
docs = loads(dumps(collection.aggregate(
[{
    '$match' : {
        '_id' : '$name',
        'metric_a' : {'$avg' : '$metric_a'},
        'metric_b' : {'$avg' : '$metric_b'},
        metric_c: {'$avg' : '$metric_c'},
    },'$match' : {'date' : {'$gte' : date_obj}}
    
}])))
```

This ends up grouping each document with a different date separately. What am I missing?

Comment: `$avg` aggregation operator can be used within a `$group` and `$project` (aliases, `$addFields` and `$set`) stages only. Also, please post a sample input document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution;

```
docs = loads(dumps(collection.aggregate(
[
    {'$match' : {'date' : {'$gte' : date_obj}}},
    {
        '$group' : {
            '_id' : '$name',
            'metric_a' : {'$avg' : '$metric_a'},
            'metric_b' : {'$avg' : '$metric_b'},
            'metric_c' : {'$avg' : '$metric_c'},
            'info' : {'$last' : '$info'}
        }
    }
])))
```

Pretty intuitive, set conditions first and then how and what you want returned.